# Returning Json inside Object adding '\' in data

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a generic controller which will return json value ,that it will get from any API.
I am trying to send response by putting inside an object but its appending / at every ", please suggest how to send result as json value.

```
Response oResponse=new Response();
Map<String,Object> result=(Map<String,Object>) service.getData();
res.setData(result.get("result"));
res.setResponseCode("200");
res.setResponseMessage("API result fetched successfully");

RESULT :
    {
      "responseCode": "000",
      "responseMessage": "API result fetched successfully",
      "data": "{\"info\":\"SUCCESS\",\"warn\":\"\",\"error\":\"\",\"responseCode\":\"200\",\"responseData\":{\"logindetails\":{\"host\":\"localhost:8080\",\"connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"content-length\":\"145\",\"origin\":\"chrome-extension:\\/\\/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\",\"apiurl\":\"abc-web-api\\/12345wer\\/testE2B\\/login\",\"user-agent\":\"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/58.0.3029.110 Safari\\/537.36\",\"content-type\":\"multipart\\/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6NUlvB1E7FBrRORE\",\"projectkey\":\"abc120\",\"cache-control\":\"no-cache\",\"postman-token\":\"81df53c2-7702-2691-f168-b544daa0e20b\",\"token\":\"YJJ7Y2khYj3he+4aNJ9WYCFLJfhGrpNrZ4JMyoiYtjnmh19UYe1vwoPYQ2Q==\",\"accept\":\"*\\/*\",\"accept-encoding\":\"gzip, deflate, br\",\"accept-language\":\"en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\"}}}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce a json responslike below, you need to have **org.json** jar file

you can send response like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourData);
resp.getWriter().write(jsonString);
```

if you are using maven , then add this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: "resp" is the object of which class?

Comment: it is HttpServletResponse resp, i assume you are using httpServlet , well if you are not using that, set response type to json and simply pass your return value in  `mapper.writeValueAsString(response)`.

Comment: String jsonInString = response.getWriter().write(jsonString), I tried this but its saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String"

Comment: that is how you pass the json response to http response, you can set the content type to json and return `jsonString` only ,which is string

Comment: Response res=new Response();//this is my class and I am returning the object of this class, I am not returning Object of HttpServletResponse

Comment: then  `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourData); return jsonString` will be enough

Comment: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(result.get("result"));                                                    but the results same

Comment: now it added more '/'  ----->                                                                
     "data": "\"{\\\"info\\\":\\\"SUCCESS\\\",\\\"warn\\\":\\\"\\\"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144943/discussion-between-sop-and-parlad-neupane).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @JsonRawValue annotation to your data field.
This will serialize/deserialize the json as it is.

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html